# Disposing two objects pointed

Tags: c#, .net, ip, ip-camera

I have an app which streams image of an ip camera. 
The problem is when I close the app it says that 1 object is still alive (not disposed).

The code when the problem occurs is:

```
public override void Render(float dt)
        {
            camera.Lock();
            if (newCameraFrame)
            {
                //Texture tmp = new Texture();
                cameraTexture = camera.Texture;
                newCameraFrame = false;
            }
            base.Render(dt);
            camera.Unlock();
        }
```

the problem occurs in line: `cameraTexture = camera.Texture;`
I dispose both variables succesfully, but it still appears that something is holding them. 
Do u have any directions to give me where shall i look for the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do these objects implement the IDisposable interface?

Then you should use them in a using block:

```
using(var cameraTexture = camera.Texture())
{
   //..do all necessary things
}

//...here the object will be automatically disposed of
```

The `IDisposable()` pattern is the keyword you should be looking for...